# Android studio aspectj - how to install aspectjtools

Tags: android, gradle, aspectj

Following [this tutorial on aspectj for android,](http://fernandocejas.com/2014/08/03/aspect-oriented-programming-in-android/) which i suspect is outdated but correct me if im wrong.  Im having trouble getting it to run.  Here is the build.gradle file on the app level:

```
 import com.android.build.gradle.LibraryPlugin
import org.aspectj.bridge.IMessage
import org.aspectj.bridge.MessageHandler
import org.aspectj.tools.ajc.Main

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-library' //ISN'T THIS DEPRECATED ???????????


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.uen229.myaspectjapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.1'
}

android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    LibraryPlugin plugin = project.plugins.getPlugin(LibraryPlugin)
    JavaCompile javaCompile = variant.javaCompile
    javaCompile.doLast {
        String[] args = ["-showWeaveInfo",
                         "-1.5",
                         "-inpath", javaCompile.destinationDir.toString(),
                         "-aspectpath", javaCompile.classpath.asPath,
                         "-d", javaCompile.destinationDir.toString(),
                         "-classpath", javaCompile.classpath.asPath,
                         "-bootclasspath", plugin.project.android.bootClasspath.join(
                File.pathSeparator)]

        MessageHandler handler = new MessageHandler(true);
        new Main().run(args, handler)

        def log = project.logger
        for (IMessage message : handler.getMessages(null, true)) {
            switch (message.getKind()) {
                case IMessage.ABORT:
                case IMessage.ERROR:
                case IMessage.FAIL:
                    log.error message.message, message.thrown
                    break;
                case IMessage.WARNING:
                case IMessage.INFO:
                    log.info message.message, message.thrown
                    break;
                case IMessage.DEBUG:
                    log.debug message.message, message.thrown
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

WHEN I try to sync gradle i get the following build error:`Error:(7, 0) Cannot add extension with name 'android', as there is an extension already registered with that name.`

All i want to do is set up aspectj for android using aspectj:aspectj-tools dependency per the article.

Comment: I don't know what is aspectJ tools, but may you find this useful: http://fernandocejas.com/2014/08/03/aspect-oriented-programming-in-android/

Comment: Check https://github.com/square/assertj-android

Comment: To your first comment, your sending me the link that is already in my question. thats the tutorial im following.  AspectJ is for code injection. For your second comment,  I am not looking for assertJ, i need aspectJ. its a code injector.  you need to research what is AOP - aspect oriented programming. its another paradigm. Maybe if you did the tutorial you could help me find out what im doing wrong.

Comment: You may try my plugin, which support app and library projects: https://github.com/Archinamon/GradleAspectJ-Android

About error: you cannot create a module with `com.android.application` and `com.android.library` both. Only one of them :)